# terraform : passing variables from resource to data block

Tags: variables, terraform, cloud-init

I'd like to dynamically pass the variable `count.index` from an instance resource to a cloud_init data block. This index aims to set the instance hostname.

Here is the data block :

```
data "template_file" "script" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/init.yml")}"
  vars = {
    username = "${var.username}"
    private_key = "${var.ssh_private_key}"
    public_key = "${var.ssh_public_key}"
    aws_access_key_id = "${var.aws_access_key_id}"
    aws_secret_access_key = "${var.aws_secret_access_key}"
    aws_session_token = "${var.aws_session_token}"
    aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"
    ips = "10.0.1.0/24"
    dbpasswd = "abc123"
    hname = "${var.hostname}"
  }
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true
  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = "${data.template_file.script.rendered}"
  }
}
```

And here the resource :

```
resource "aws_instance" "controller" {
  count = var.count_clt
  ami           = data.aws_ami.centos.id
  instance_type = var.itype
  key_name = var.keyname
  user_data = var.cloudinit_config
  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.controller.id
    device_index         = 0
  }
  tags = {
    Name ="egu-${var.hostname_prefix}-${count.index + 1}"
  }
}
```

I'm wondering whether it's some how possible to pass variable at line `user_data` which actually contains `data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered`

Thanks.

Comment: Is this code running without errors? You want to pass the `count.index` to `template_cloudinit_config`? Where would you use it?

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks, yes it works. The real one uses modules though. I can combine the two module in one if necessary. This is for aws provider. Yes, I'd basically like to pass the `count.index` to `template_cloudinit_config`.

Comment: Do you want to fetch multiple instances of template_cloudinit_config? For each count? Otherwise, which count.index do you actually want to pass to it?

Comment: @Karl, yes, my point is to have one clouninit that works for multiple instances and set the hostname dynamically regarding the index.

Comment: When you say hostname, you mean this `hname = "${var.hostname}"`?

Comment: @MarkoE, right, basically set this variable to `${var.hostname_prefix}-${count.index + 1}` for instance, or forget about this one and set an other one to pass the index only.

Comment: Still pretty unclear to me what you want to achieve. Where do you actually want to use `count.index` on `template_cloudinit_config`? It looks like what you want to do is to create multiple instances of `aws_instance.controller`, and have each of those instances reference an instance of `data.template_cloudinit_config.config`  and you want to use `count.index` as a way of ensuring the right instance is referenced. But I am grasing at straws a bit, need a clearer explanation

Comment: Thanks @Karl, I posted the solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.

I generate *n* `template_cloudinit_config.config` data and pick up one with `count.index` in the resource.

Here is the code :

```
data "template_file" "script" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/init.yml")}"
  count = var.count_clt
  vars = {
    username = "${var.username}"
    private_key = "${var.ssh_private_key}"
    public_key = "${var.ssh_public_key}"
    aws_access_key_id = "${var.aws_access_key_id}"
    aws_secret_access_key = "${var.aws_secret_access_key}"
    aws_session_token = "${var.aws_session_token}"
    aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"
    ips = "10.0.1.0/24"
    dbpasswd = "abc123"
    hname = "${var.hostname_prefix}-${count.index + 1}"
  }
}
```

```
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true
  count = var.count_clt
  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content  = element(data.template_file.script.*.rendered, count.index)
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "controller" {
  count = var.count_clt
  ami           = data.aws_ami.centos.id
  instance_type = var.itype
  key_name = var.keyname
  user_data = element(data.template_cloudinit_config.config.*.rendered, count.index)

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.controller[count.index].id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  tags = {
    Name = element(local.hostsnames,count.index)
  }
}
```

Thanks for having tried to help.